# No Module named pygame.locals

Tags: python, import, pygame

I tried to import the following with pygame installed :

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
```

and I get this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\gx\Desktop\Library\p1\test.py", line 5, in <module>
          from pygame.locals import *
ImportError: No module named 'pygame.locals'
```

I had found similar problems but none seemed to really help. 
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: do you have a file named `pygame.py` in the directory you're running your script in?  what happens when you `import pygame;print pygame.__file__`?

Comment: I think pygame already includes locals and that you are only supposed to import it if you aren't importing pygame but want to access locals.

Answer (score 1):

Don't even bother importing `pygame.locals`, since you already have imported that by importing `pygame`. Also, take a look at the comment from @IfLoop.

Comment: the point of `importing * from pygame.locals` is to access all the locals with just their names. So instead of having to use pygame.KEYDOWN, a KEYDOWN would suffice.

Comment: True, but it causes problems. It also isn't hard to type `pygame.KEYDOWN` instead of `KEYDOWN`.